# Ask `\autoref` to display environment name without number

Tags: hyperref, memoir, cleveref

I'm using the `memoir` class and I define theorems with `thmtools`. Theorems often have a name, besides being numbered. I'm looking to write a `\fullref` command that outputs the name of the environment (here, `Theorem`) along with its given name, but without its number. (This command should work for any environment for which a name is defined, e.g., via `\myenvautorefname`.)

I used to use the following command, found here on TeX SE:

`\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\namecref{#1}\ \nameref*{#1}}}`

Unfortunately, `memoir` and `cleveref` conflict with each other. So I'd like to make do without `cleveref`.

It seems that I should be able to achieve the same effect with `autoref` only. The command

`\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1}\ \nameref*{#1}}}`

*almost* does what I want, except that it displays the theorem number between `Theorem` and the theorem name.

Here's a MWE that illustrates the command above:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1}\ \nameref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[Whatever]
    \label{thm:whatever}
    Some witty theorem.
  \end{theorem}

  % The following outputs "Theorem 1 Whatever".
  % I would like "Theorem Whatever".
  Consider \fullref{thm:whatever}.
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the incompatibility exactly? If I add `cleveref` into your MWE and substitute your original definition of `\fullref`, it seems to do what I'd expect, I think.

Comment: Also, the documentation of `cleveref` says `memoir` is compatible. According to that, you just need to use a small workaround in the case of labels for sub-captions in the case of sub-figures. [Note, this is for the current version. An older version was apparently incompatible, according to the version history.]

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `cleveref`?!

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\namecref{#1}\ \nameref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}[Whatever]
    \label{thm:whatever}
    Some witty theorem.
  \end{theorem}

  % The following outputs "Theorem 1 Whatever".
  % I would like "Theorem Whatever".
  Consider \fullref{thm:whatever}.
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>cleveref</code> with <code>memoir</code>]

Answer (score 2):

The following uses [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) as an alternative to [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) to create a new *property* called `envname` (similar to what is provided by the `zref-env` module) which stores either `\<env>autorefname` or `\@currenvir` - the `curr`ent `envir`onment name:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}% Loads nameref

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{envname}[??]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\@currenvir autorefname\endcsname\relax
    \@currenvir
  \else
    \csname \@currenvir autorefname\endcsname
  \fi}%
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\oldlabel\label
  \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{envname}\oldlabel{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\fullref}[1]{%
  \zref@refused{#1}% Mark label as used
  \hyperref[#1]{\zref@extract{#1}{envname}\ \nameref*{#1}}}
\makeatother


\declaretheorem{theorem}
\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Whatever]
  \label{thm:whatever}
  Some witty theorem.
\end{theorem}

% The following outputs "Theorem Whatever".
Consider \fullref{thm:whatever}.
\end{document}
```